# next(null) doesn't work on BehaviourSubject

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have a BehaviorSubject object which I initialise as follows:

```
// Note value is an URL to an existing image 
// retrieved via an API call later on
let value = null;
navbarLogoImage = new BehaviorSubject<string>(value);
```

Over the duration of my application's lifecycle, I set it as follows:

```
this.builderNavbarService.navbarLogoImage.next('https://i.imgur.com/v7yoDaH.png');
```

However, when I want to set it to null, it is ignored and the state doesn't update:

```
this.builderNavbarService.navbarLogoImage.next(null);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The question has tag "angular" but it shouldn't have this tag, right?

Comment: No, it's correct. See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/behavioursubject-angular-demo

Comment: `.next(null)` is not ignored. It will change its internal value to `null`.